# Python : Selenium does not start the firefox browser

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, webdriver

Try to run firefox through webdriver, but firefox does not run. Specify everything correctly (firefox path), even if nothing happened.
I would really appreciate your help.

> [*]geckodriver.exe was moved to / usr / bin

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\Firefox.exe")#path of Firefox.exe
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

Comment: Do you see any error?

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the driver in your PATH, or you can specify the path to the driver.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="path\to\geckodriver.exe")
```

If you have not, you can download it from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and put it in your python folder.

Comment: **Disable the marionette it worked, but it doesn't load any URL.**